# SoundCloud SC.oEmbed returns html iframe with 404

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud, oembed

I'm trying to stream a track from soundcloud using their Javascript API, but I keep getting a 404 when asking for the stream url:

```js
 SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: false }).then(function(oEmbed) {
      var iframeContainer = document.getElementById('soundcloud-preview-iframe-<?php echo $track->id; ?>')
      iframeContainer.innerHTML = oEmbed.html;
      var iframe = iframeContainer.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
      widget<?php echo $track->id; ?> = SC.Widget(iframe);
      widget<?php echo $track->id; ?>.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        jQuery(".soundcloud-preview-control-<?php echo $track->id; ?>").addClass("soundcloud-preview-control-play").html('<!-- -->');
      });
      widget<?php echo $track->id; ?>.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function() {
        widget<?php echo $track->id; ?>.getPosition(function(positionSC) {
          if( (secondsLimit*1000)<Math.floor(positionSC) ) {
            widget<?php echo $track->id; ?>.pause();
            curSongId = '';
            jQuery(".soundcloud-preview-control-<?php echo $track->id; ?>").removeClass("soundcloud-preview-control-stop").addClass("soundcloud-preview-control-play");
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

I receive multiple 404 errors on console related at this call related at oEmbed.html json object:
https://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?auto_play=false&url=xxx

I'd like to know why using their JS API doesn't work.